# Find the maximum of the function $e^x-1-x$ over $-1\leq x\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, optimization

> Find the maximum over $-1\leq x\leq 1$ of the function $e^x-1-x$.

My teacher said to check the mix, first, we have two values $e^{-1} \to =.5$ and $e^{-2}\to =0.1$.

Then, he said the answer will be $0.5$.

Can someone explain that please...

Comment: We want the maximum over the interval, and we get a bunch of critical points as a result. But since we want the maximum over the whole interval, we choose 0.5 instead of 0.1.

Comment: Are you aware of the first derivative test?

Comment: the first derivat is e^x-1 the f'(x)=0--->x=0 ,,i do not understand how we get e^-2?

Answer (score 0):

There is something stange is your problem.

If $f(x)=e^x-1-x$, its derivative is $f'(x)=e^x-1$ which cancels for $x=0$, being negative for all $x<0$ and positive for all $x>0$. So, the maximum of $f(x)$ will be at one of the bounds of the interval but corresponds to the right bound; please notice that $f(1)=e-2=0.718282$ and that $f(-1)=\frac{1}{e}=0.367879$.

$f(x)=e^x-1-x=\frac{1}{2}$ has as solutions $x=-1.19829$ which is outside the range under consideration and $x=0.857677$.

Please check if you did not forget one piece of information in the problem.